# Insert XML node from one file to another - using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I need help with writing a PowerShell script to read a XML node from one XML file and insert it into another XML file. Here is the XML from the input file:

```
<configuration>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <variable name="LoggingDirectory" value="D:/Logging/"/>
 <include file="${LoggingDirectory}Config/Framework.nlog.xml"/>
</nlog>
</configuration>
```

How do I read the `nlog` XML node and insert it into another XML file?

Comment: I would need to know what the "other XML file" looks like before I can assist with this.

Comment: Hi Trevor, the other file is the .NET framework the machine.config file. 

    <configuration> 
      <configSections> 
         <section name = "appSettings" type ="..." >
          ... 

        </configSectins> 
        <system.serviceModel>
        ..
        </system.serviceModel>
       ..
     </configuration>